# Meaning to lyrics of Syd Barrett's song *Baby Lemonade*

Tags: lyrics, meaning

Can someone offer their interpretation of the [Syd Barrett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syd_Barrett) song called [*Baby Lemonade*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Lemonade) from his solo album [*Barrett*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_(album))?

[Here](https://genius.com/Syd-barrett-baby-lemonade-lyrics) are the lyrics, and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNgxNxkUQF0) you can listen to the song on YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

Hard not to make this a personal answer, and hard to find reference points to make it objective. The song is clearly not telling a story, so more likely it is about describing a mood or state of mind.

Syd's behaviour at this time was erratic, and his mental health was fragile - although at the same time he was able to perform and give interviews.
[1971 interview, Melody Maker](http://sydbarrett.net/syd-barrett-articles/syd-barrett-interview/)

The [wiki article for the album "Barrett"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_(album))
talks of it as :

> "The lyrics that describe the way for a person to kill time  (such as
>   the line "In the clock they sent / Through a washing machine")."

quoting Rob Chapman's (2010) book, "Syd Barrett: A Very Irregular Head"

Not sure about that myself : for me, like many of Syd's songs, it hints at depression, loneliness, a feeling of alienation, all expressed in a restrained whimsical English way.

> ```
> "In the sad town
>     cold iron hands
>     clap the party of clowns outside"
> ```

"Baby Lemonade" is maybe a nickname for a lover or close friend.

```
"I'm screaming, I met you this way
you're nice to me like ice...
come around, make it soon, so alone
please, please, Baby Lemonade"
```

Probably not wise to look for a total explanation of every reference.